# using .htaccess want to change the # as?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

if anybody hits this url:

> ***www.facebook.com/index.php#sk=inbox***

then .htaccess will hits the server as:

> ***www.facebook.com/index.php?sk=inbox***

so that i will get the value of sk through php as:

> ***echo $_GET['id'];***

please help me **ASAP...**
i am waiting for your replies...

thankyou...

Comment: Please stop putting your comments as answers, use **add comment** link (under the answer/question) or update your question with new details.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers normally don't pass the Fragment (the #sk=inbox part) to the server (unless maybe through AJAX calls?), so nothing you can do with .htaccess.

Need more info about your scenario: Why are clients hitting the above URL and can you change the clients instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think JS can help you here, so if some one hits `a.com/#b=c` the default page loads and in the html JS takes care of `#b=c` and does further processing, my be triggering an AJAX call to load the entire HTML mark up again. But .htaccess wont even see anything beyond #  in a URL as it will never receive it.